# Safe way of altering prices in shopping cart

Tags: php, javascript, paypal, shopping-cart

I am trying to create quite simple project. I will explain it on an example.

**Description on what i am trying to do using simply example:**
Let say you can upload two images to my site, select size (1000x500 or 2000x1000), and write some text. My site would merge these 2 images into one, of course resizing it properly, and write some text on top of the images. That's quite simple. After generating such image, it sends you to a page where you can preview the image and there is a Paypal button with 1$ price. Everything in `$_POST[]` when it comes to PHP and GD so it should be safe.

I want to allow user push "next image" saving the one he already made, and make another one. Same process, he finishes at a site with 2 image previews, and a button saying 2$. Again shouldn't be that hard.

**Problem and the question:**
But here comes my question. User created 2 images, both 1000x500, and he see both previews. And i want to let him change **ON THIS SCREEN** one image to 2000x1000, but that also means change of the price. So is that possible without reloading the page, to ***change SAFELY quantity or some properties of images***, also altering price on paypal button?
I am sure javascript isnt the best idea here. I saw paypal lets me use "Add drop-down menu with price/option" but i cant rly use it determine which photo gonna be big one, and which one small one. Cuz with 3 photos there are already quite some possibilities (all small, 1st big, second big, two big etc)...

**Solution i wish not to use, but didn't find any other so far:**
Or i have to let him change these properties/values in a form (disabling buy button somehow), and then pass everything using `$_POST[]` which would redirect him to page, with proper button?

I know its kinda messy, but i tried to explain it best i was able too. My english isn't the best. Hope you guys understand what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not `messy` and many website does it, example: 
On many Buy-Pages, when you choose US as a `country` the page submits itself to the server and a new `state` dropdown appears. 
You can certainly do that, or use AJAX. But, if there are only a few options I WOULD use JS/jQuery to change the prices (especially since it's such low prices and since the prices are static).

Comment: Well i guess i will use reloading then. I am afraid of using JS/jQuery, cuz i was thinking of hiding/showing other buy buttons, when properties changed, but that can be easily "hacked" and some1 may pay for other photos than he generated. Thanks for your time.